# Is underscore _.every method synchronous or not?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to use the _.every method(Not using _.each method because I can't break it _.each loop) for traversing the array and break the traversal on a condition. So I want to know is _.every method is synchronous or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it sync

```
  function every(collection, callback, thisArg) {
      var result = true;
      callback = lodash.createCallback(callback, thisArg, 3);

      var index = -1,
          length = collection ? collection.length : 0;

      if (typeof length == 'number') {
        while (++index < length) {
          if (!(result = !!callback(collection[index], index, collection))) {
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        forOwn(collection, function(value, index, collection) {
          return (result = !!callback(value, index, collection));
        });
      }
      return result;
    }
```